# How to read promo code from Facebook App Invite

Tags: java, android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here is the code to recieve promocode after installation from playstore

```
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    Uri targetUrl = AppLinks.getTargetUrlFromInboundIntent(this, getIntent());
    if (targetUrl != null) 
    {
        Log.i("facebook_app_invite","if");
        Log.i("Activity", "App Link Target URL: " + targetUrl.toString());
    } 
    else 
    {
        AppLinkData.fetchDeferredAppLinkData(getApplicationContext(),new AppLinkData.CompletionHandler() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onDeferredAppLinkDataFetched(AppLinkData appLinkData) 
            {
                 //process applink data
                Log.i("facebook_app_invite","else");
                if (appLinkData != null) 
                {
                    Log.i("facebook_app_invite",appLinkData.getPromotionCode());
                    String promoCode = appLinkData.getPromotionCode();
                    if (promoCode != null)
                    {
                        Log.i("facebook_app_invite",promoCode.toString());
                                // ... execute code related to the promotion ...
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("appLinkData is null");
                    Log.i("facebook_app_invite", "appLinkData is null");

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have used following code to send Facebook app Invite

```
try
                {
                    CallbackManager  sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                    if (AppInviteDialog.canShow())
                    {
                        AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                                .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                                .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                                .setPromotionDetails("Promotional Message", "promocode").build();
                        AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(Ced_SharePage.this);
                        appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result)
                            {
                                Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                                finish();
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel()
                            {
                                Log.d("Invitation", "Cancel");
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError(FacebookException e)
                            {
                                Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
                            }
                        });
                        appInviteDialog.show(content);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```

When I send the Facebook app invite the Facebook app shows the notification and prompts the user to install the app , after installing the app when we try to get appLinkData is returns null

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this?